# Wednesday Addams' shoes

Tags: wednesday

In the new Netflix series, "Wednesday", about Wednesday Addams, what's up with her shoes?

I don't usually notice shoes*, but what's with all the super thick soles? Almost all of them seem to be +2" thick. Is that something the director wanted to help keep the relatively short actress in the frame better or is that simply a "goth chick" style?

They seemed more like what Lurch would wear, rather than a girl/young woman who professes in the series not to care what people think of her, except when she likes how they feel about her as "different".

I found an article about the shoes, but it was geared more towards where to buy them than anything else. And all of them seemed to be high-end/expensive brands, so is it just a marketing thing so the series can get sponsors?

Is there even a single answer or is it more like a combination of multiple factors that include reasons I haven't mentioned?

<sub>* Even though I don't normally notice shoes, these were almost obnoxiously large, to the point where I thought they were distracting away from the story, which is why I'm asking this question at all.</sub>

Comment: The question as stated is "what's up with the character's shoes?" followed by opinion-based criticism of a TV show's costume choices. I have seen way better questions than this closed in five minutes. Then they get an answer and pick a fight with the person who answered. Voting to close this.

Comment: @ruffdove, I don't get how asking for clarification of an answer is "picking a fight". Also the how is half a sentence of this question the main focus of all your criticism? Why aren't you suggesting I edit out the opinion to make the question better, instead of trying to close it? It seems like you are the one trying to pick a fight.

Comment: That's what all the hot chicks wore when I was in HS. I found it pleasantly distracting that she *DGAF* about fashion.

Comment: I don't know if it really answers your question but creepers have always been the "in" shoe for "outcast" groups, and they've been around since like 1949. I think the stereotype that "outcasts / goths/ punk rockers / etc wear thick soled shoes" is a pretty common so this probably just follows suit since it's the entertainment industry we're talking about.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothel_creeper

Comment: *Your mom wears combat boots.* "A woman wearing combat boots or boots of sort can be perceived as having a strong personality and are often the ones to take control of the situation. They also like to have a plan for the future. Believe it or not, but boots wearers also are believed to have a masculine side in their personalities." - belief isn't required; just watch the show.

Comment: @Mazura, actually, that phrase is an insult. It basically says your mom is ugly, homeless, or a prostitute, among other meanings. https://wordhistories.net/2020/07/16/mother-wears-army-boots/ I don't believe any of those apply to Wednesday. BTW, where did you get your quote? Also, I did "just watch the show" and enjoyed it. FYI, it's pretty dismissive and condescending to tell someone to "just shut up and...", even if the "shut up" part is implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a case of the tail wagging the dog. Actress Jenny Ortega is a little over five feet tall. With the addition of a pair of her [*Prada Monolith shoes*](https://www.prada.com/gb/en/p/monolith-brushed-leather-lace-up-shoes/1E708L_B4L_F0002_F_B055) (she also rocks a pair of [*Slider Platform Sneakers*](https://www.nordstrom.com/s/slider-platform-sneaker-women/7090230?origin=category-personalizedsort&breadcrumb=Home%2FWomen%2FShoes%2FSneakers%20%26%20Athletic&color=002)), she adds approximately three inches of height without the need to wear high heels, something that would be out of character for someone as retro-gothic as Wednesday.

> Apart from Wednesday's on-screen best friend Enid, played by Emma Myers, most of the cast has a stark difference in height to Ortega. Myers stands at 5'3", but many others are between 5'5" 1/2, with Luis Guzmán as Gomez Addams, up to 6'3" which is how tall Gwendoline Christie playing Principal Weems is. In order to make sure that Wednesday isn't overshadowed by her co-stars, the production uses a variety of tricks to ensure the height differences aren't too distracting.
>
> In addition to helping establish the character of Wednesday and give
> her a unique sense of style, the platforms helped to place the actors
> on a more level playing field in order to let the acting take center
> stage.
>
> <sub><sup>[ScreenRant: How Tall Is Wednesday’s Jenna Ortega?](https://screenrant.com/how-tall-is-jenna-ortega-in-wednesday/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 6):

All the cool kids are wearing chunky-sole shoes this year. I just picked the first shoe shop I could think of - https://www.deichmann.com/en-gb/women

[image]

3rd pair from the left are not dissimilar. I didn't go hunting for an exact match, this is literally just the first thing you're presented with on a fairly random choice of high street shoe shop.

More similar 'school shoes' on https://www.deichmann.com/en-gb/ladies-shoes/brogues/loafers/c-wsl1d.
These links will obviously be totally different next year, but I'm sure we don't need a whole pageful of school shoe pictures cluttering the site ;)

It started with the kids who would identify as something along the lines of emo or goth - which would certainly suit - and also seems to have some anime or manga connotation a year or so ago & has now gone mainstream.

[image]

Comment: I understand this is a fashion trend, but even though there are other goth/emo kids in the school, I didn't happen to notice any of them wearing these types of shoes, and Wednesday seems to wear exclusively these thick soled shoes. And she doesn't seem to wear many of these shoes repeatedly, as if she has an inexhaustible source/variety of these shoes, even though her side of the dorm room is fairly bare. Here's the article I found that lists her shoes, or at least some of them. https://www.popbuzz.com/tv-film/netflix-wednesday/shoes-outfits-where-to-buy-prada-naked-wolfe/

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is? Why did one of Hollywood's most prestigious costume designers think the star of the show should never wear the same outfit twice? As she's stuck in school uniform for a good part of the show, what else was there to play with?

Comment: So you're saying it was because of trying to prop up the ego of the costume designer rather than to fit within the scope of the character that Wednesday wore those shoes? There were dozens of other characters to design costumes for, which they did and did well. I get that she's from a well off family, but her character is one of minimalism, so changing shoes multiple times a day and rarely re-wearing the same shoes doesn't fit.

Comment: You're really questioning that for decades Hollywood has avoided dressing the female star in the same outfit two scenes running if they can possibly avoid it? You've not been watching carefully.

Comment: I guess you're right, I haven't been "watching carefully" the wardrobe changes. I guess I've been mistaken to think that the character progression and story, as well as dialogue and action were the important parts. I'll also say that scenery isn't really important to me, either. Sure, it adds to the story, but usually isn't critical to it. But what you say still boils down to an out-of-universe answer for this particular question, instead of something relevant to the Wednesday character, which actually goes against what you say in your answer.

Comment: Now you're just being obtuse. Everything in a movie/show is important to the look & feel. You might not notice it unless you actually specialise. It's not meant to be noticed, it's meant to be felt. If she'd worn a light pink tracksuit with pale grey trainers & the show had been set in an ordinary, no uniform, urban school… would it be the same show? [BTW, the target audience will notice & will all want shoes like that.]

Comment: Me pushing back at your comment was designed to be just as obtuse as your comment. You're one of the few people to ever state that I don't notice things, even though I correctly predicted the 2 main villains in this series less than halfway through the season. Also, the wardrobe you mention is also not in character for Wednesday Addams. The school could have been set in a "typical" high school and, no, it wouldn't have been as interesting. Still, it wasn't a critical aspect of the story. In fact, it's a over-worn trope that "odd kids" need an odd school: Harry Potter, X-Men, Sky High, Zoom...

Comment: I'm done. You don't want an answer you want to someone to just agree with you. I don't agree with you.

Comment: You answered with 3 different explanations which contradict each other, so I'm trying to get a straight answer without the snark of the last 2 answers-in-comments. I don't care if you agree with me, I just don't think you should be making judgement calls about me while doing it.

Comment: Explain how I have 3 different explanations. I have one. "All the cool kids are wearing them." The rest was some attempt to correct your misconceptions… which all failed, because you don't believe they are misconceptions, apparently. You are getting more & more dismissive with each reply - well, now I am too.

Comment: Your 1st comment was to say that it was solely the costume designers discretion to change up the shoes because the rest of Wednesday's wardrobe was a uniform, which minimizes the other outfits she wore even while at school. Your 2nd comment was that it was a major part of film history that women's wardrobe changed every scene, while being judgmental about my powers of observation. These 2 are different from each other and different from your posted answer, which boils down to "it's part of her character" that incidentally is now a fad for "all the cool kids".

Comment: My 1st comment was to trying to figure out how only 1 person out of this whole school decided to wear the goth/emo trend and the cool kids trend. After that, it was to figure out why you were changing your answer and push back on your rude comments. I even gave a self-deprecating comment, which you took and ran with, then complained I was somehow the rude one. Really? And you think I'm the one that has problems with observation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended conversation.  If this must be continued then I suggest taking it to chat - though given the tone this probably isn't the best idea.  Please be aware that people are *attempting* to give an answer to you in order to be helpful to you - so by and large I would assume good intent if they don't understand your problem.